# Update multiple columns/rows case statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have looked at similar questions previously but they seem to update a single column with multiple case conditions and the one answer I found for multiple columns seems a little long.

Let's say I have a table like this:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Value 1 |  |  |  |
| Second | Value 2 |  |  |  |
| .... | .... |  |  |  |
| Twelfth | Value 3 |  |  |  |

I want to use column_1 as a key and update column 3, column 4 and column 5 with known values.

My initial query guess was:

```
UPDATE table SET
Column_3, Column_4, Column_5
CASE 
When Column_1 = 'First' Then 'first_col_3_val', 'first_col_4_val', 'first_col_5_val'
When Column_1 = 'Second' Then 'second_col_3_val', 'second_col_4_val', 'second_col_5_val'
...
When Column_1 = 'Tenth' Then 'tenth_col_3_val', 'tenth_col_4_val', 'tenth_col_5_val'
END
```

The solution for a similar question was

```
UPDATE table 
SET Column_3
CASE
When Column_1 = 'First' Then 'first_col_3_val'
When Column_1 = 'Second' Then 'second_col_3_val'
...
END
SET Column_4
CASE
When Column_1 = 'First' Then 'first_col_4_val'
When Column_1 = 'Second' Then 'second_col_4_val'
...
END
SET Column_5
CASE
When Column_1 = 'First' Then 'first_col_5_val'
When Column_1 = 'Second' Then 'second_col_5_val'
...
END
```

Would my initial query work? Or am I looking for a different SQL feature like Duplicate keys? I read up on a MySQL If() function but I'm working with Microsoft SQL. Thanks for the help!

Comment: _Would my initial query work?_ You can try this for yourself with a simple demo script and know the answer. And that simple demo script could then be used as a basis for your discussion here. Short answer - no.

Comment: Your query is a syntax error, you don't use `update` or `case expressions` in that way. Why would you not just try it?

Comment: Didn't realize how to get a demo working and wanted to check my understanding of the way the SQL syntax worked. I assumed my understanding was flawed that's why I asked the question.

Comment: I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction. The only discussion If found that was similar was this one: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=36264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you are looking for something like this:

```
update T
    set T.column_3 = V.column_3
    ,T.column_4 = V.column_4
    ,T.column_5 = V.column_5
from table T
    inner join
    (
        values
        ('first', 'first_3', 'first_4', 'first_5'),
        ('second', 'second_3', 'second_4', 'second_5')
        ...
    ) V (column_1, column_3, column_4, column_5)
    on V.column_1 = T.column_1
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it with fiddle and it worked. This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it! For anyone else with the same question here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4cc3b3eee15d0ed546cb6b9ad24813d7

Answer (score 0):

This is bad design. You're doing something wrong if came to this question.

```
create table tab(
    Column_1 varchar(100),
    Column_2 varchar(100),
    Column_3 varchar(100),
    Column_4 varchar(100),
    Column_5 varchar(100));

insert tab (Column_1) values ('First'), ('Second'), ('Twelfth');

select top 0 * into #tmp from tab;

insert #tmp (Column_1, Column_3, Column_4, Column_5) values
('First', 'first_col_3_val', 'first_col_4_val', 'first_col_5_val'),
('Second', 'second_col_3_val', 'second_col_4_val', 'second_col_5_val'),
('Twelfth', 'twelfth_col_3_val', 'twelfth_col_4_val', 'twelfth_col_5_val');

update  tab
set     Column_3 = #tmp.Column_3,
        Column_4 = #tmp.Column_4,
        Column_5 = #tmp.Column_5
from    tab join #tmp on tab.Column_1 = #tmp.Column_1;

select * from tab;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ffcc2e1563e6eb70014bbfef4cdc3c7)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to submit update/submit the data in one query, but it seems that using a temporary table might be the best way to do this.